# How to mark a column for deletion or exclude in ActiveRecord PostgreSQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Rails keeps track of the existing columns ([magic happens here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fd18b98dd90d738af265cf5b8f0d66ca11010132/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb#L779-L810)) and uses this when loading joined tables with `.eager_load`. `.eager_load` produces a SQL query that looks like:

```sql
SELECT "models"."id" AS t0_r0,
...
"models"."deprecated_column" as t0_r1,
... as t1_r0,
...
```

this works well for most of the situations. But becomes problematic when dropping columns.

I wonder if there's a rails way of marking a column for deletion so that it's not selected for future eager loads.

Reading the active record source code, looks like if the pg_attribute would have `attisdropped = true`, then the column wouldn't be selected. But I'm not sure how to set it through activerecord migrations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer in Rails docs, there `ignored_columns` that needs to be set: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-ignored_columns-3D

Once the updated code is deployed, it should be safe to drop the column.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you exactly need, but it looks like this might help:

```
Model.connection.schema_cache.clear!
Model.reset_column_information
```

Comment: This might help, but that means that we need to run this before every time we query the table. I'll try to explain again:
1. Request hits the rails app, where ModelA joined with other models is requested.
2. A migration is run, and `ModelA#deprecated` column is dropped.
3. SQL query tries to read all available columns of ModelA, generated at the step 1.

The 3rd step fails, because by the generated query wasn't aware of the dropped column.

Comment: A good practice is to reload each related application after migration. I don't see another way

Comment: that's very hard with zero downtime, as there are multiple instances of the app are running.